# Application not working in android nougat

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

this is my code for get permissions...but still its stop when user perform permission action(target api is 25). any other way?

```
boolean isMdevice;
boolean pstatus;
int code=1;
String[] perms = { android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS};


/////then in oncreate

isMdevice=isMarshmallowPlusDevice();
pstatus= isPermissionRequestRequired(MainActivity.this, perms, code);

////then methods

public static boolean isMarshmallowPlusDevice() {

    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public static boolean isPermissionRequestRequired(Activity activity, @NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode) {
    if (isMarshmallowPlusDevice() && permissions.length > 0) {
        List<String> newPermissionList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (PERMISSION_GRANTED != activity.checkSelfPermission(permission)) {
                newPermissionList.add(permission);

            }
        }
        if (newPermissionList.size() > 0) {
            activity.requestPermissions(newPermissionList.toArray(new String[newPermissionList.size()]), requestCode);
            return true;
        }

    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code for Check permission and ask for runtime permission:
 Add this class to your project

```
public class PermissionUtils {

public static boolean checkPermission(Context context, String permission) {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

public static void requestPermissions(Activity activity, String messageInCaseOfCustomDialog, int permissionId, String... permissions) {
   /* if (o instanceof Fragment) {
        FragmentCompat.requestPermissions((Fragment) o, permissions, permissionId);
    } else */
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,
            permissions[0])) {
        showCustomDialogForAskPermission(activity, messageInCaseOfCustomDialog, permissionId, permissions);
        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else if (/*MySharedPreference.getSharedPrefrence(activity).getBoolean(permissions[0], false)*/) { //Use your Shared Preference
        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
        showCustomDialogForGoToTheSettings(activity, messageInCaseOfCustomDialog);
        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissions, permissionId);
    }
    /*MySharedPreference.getSharedPrefrence(activity).edit().putBoolean(permissions[0], true).commit();*/    //Use your Shared Preference
}

private static void showCustomDialogForGoToTheSettings(final Activity activity, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    dialog.setTitle("Permission Required");
    dialog.setMessage(message);
    dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", activity.getPackageName(), null);
            intent.setData(uri);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}

private static void showCustomDialogForAskPermission(final Activity activity, String message, final int permissionId, final String... permissions) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    dialog.setTitle("Permission Required");
    dialog.setMessage(message);
    dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissions, permissionId);

        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

}

Now you can directly check if you  have that permission or not,Suppose you want to check for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

```
if (PermissionUtils.checkPermission(RegisterScreenActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    //Do your work
 } else {PermissionUtils.requestPermissions(RegisterScreenActivity.this, "You need to provide storage permission for this service", 101, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE});//ask for permission
 }
```

You can also track its result in onRequestPermissionsResult() methods like

```
   @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {


        case 101:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
              //permission granted, can do your work
            } else {
              //permission not granted
            }
            break;


    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply....i am trying this....did this work in nougat??...and can u pls tell me were i was wrong..

Comment: Yes it will definately work, I am also using this ,its working fine in all android version

Comment: there is already a simple methods given for check for permission,i.e. ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED; it return true is app already have permission ,false otherwise. Then why are you writing complex code for checking permission